# Disable entries in system.log

Tags: magento2

I have Magento 2.2.x and system.log grows each minute, because of entries like:

```
[2018-09-30 17:53:15] main.INFO: Add of item with id Magento_Customer::customer_manage was processed [] []
[2018-09-30 17:53:15] main.INFO: Add of item with id Magento_Customer::customer_online was processed [] []
[2018-09-30 17:53:15] main.INFO: Add of item with id Magento_Customer::customer_group was processed [] []
[2018-09-30 17:53:15] main.INFO: Add of item with id Magento_AdminNotification::system_adminnotification was processed [] []
[2018-09-30 17:53:15] main.INFO: Add of item with id Magento_Config::system_config was processed [] []
[2018-09-30 17:53:15] main.INFO: Add of item with id Magento_Indexer::system_index was processed [] []
[2018-09-30 17:53:15] main.INFO: Add of item with id Magento_Cms::cms_page was processed [] []
[2018-09-30 17:53:15] main.INFO: Add of item with id Magento_Cms::cms_block was processed [] []
[2018-09-30 17:53:15] main.INFO: Add of item with id Magento_Catalog::catalog was processed [] []
[2018-09-30 17:53:15] main.INFO: Add of item with id Magento_Catalog::catalog_products was processed [] []
[2018-09-30 17:53:15] main.INFO: Add of item with id Magento_Catalog::catalog_categories was processed [] []
[2018-09-30 17:53:15] main.INFO: Add of item with id Magento_Catalog::catalog_attributes_attributes was processed [] []
[2018-09-30 17:53:15] main.INFO: Add of item with id Magento_Catalog::catalog_attributes_sets was processed [] []
```

How can I stop Magento logging such info?

Answer (score 0):

unfortunately this direct settings are not avaliable in magento2 to disable syetem log, please check this file and comment code, it may help you

`vender\Magento\Framework\Logger\Handler\System.php` when you use the system level, logs will got to `/var/log/system.log`

Thanks, Hope it may help you.

Comment: thanks! but after next update of magento this will be overwritten, right?

Comment: yes you have to make a plugin for this file

Comment: @Divyesh if you dont want to make plugin then you can override that file just copy that file and paste in below folder.  "lib/internal/Magento/Framework/Logger/Handler/System.php"

Answer (score 0):

**Magento mode:**

see this file `vendor/magento/module-backend/Model/Menu.php`

- create a new module
- create a system.xml file with a configuration system.log enable/disable crop useless logs
- create a model/config.php file with the method that get the value from system.xml
- create a plugin around for this function `vendor/magento/module-backend/Model/Menu.php::add`
- inject config.php file custom and create an if that based on value print the log
- easy

**Brutality**

- cron that every minute remove the file with absolute path:

`* * * * *  find  /magento/path/var/log/system.log -mtime +7 -exec rm -f {} \;`

- or maybe a cron that every minute set file as empty, or something like this:

`* * * * *  find  /magento/path/var/log/system.log -mtime +7 -exec {} > true \;`

Cheers

Answer (score -3):

In magento2 this option is not exist,the setting has been removed from admin area.

if you don't want system.log then **run below command**

```
rm -rf var/log/system.log
```

Comment: thanks. but after deleting file, file is generateed again automatically ....

Comment: i know but this the best thing we can do.otherwise magento 2 have not disbale functionality of system.log.

Comment: This will not "stop Magento logging such info" (quoting the original question).